# how to plot graphic with the same Y bound

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, bounds

I have to plot graphics and compare them but it's misleading because of different y-axis upper bounds for each of them (they are all positive values).
Anyway I'm doing a cycle like this:

```
 %% check for data files
 for i=1:length(files)
    load
    plot(x,y)
 end
```

I need to change my code if I want to save the maximum upper bound on y.

```
 %% check for data files
 for i=1:length(files)
    load
    %% compare upper bounds and get the maximum
 end
 %% plot cycle
```

But then how can I use this value to plot comparable but separated graphics.
I can't plot them in only one figure because they are many. Also tell me If you think of a possible optimization for my task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ylim](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ylim.html) is what you are looking for, but if i understood you right you might also want to look at [linkaxes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linkaxes.html).

Comment: I recently discovered `linkaxes` myself, and it is amazing. It will allow you to zoom in on multiple graphs at once, which is very handy!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ylim`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/ylim.html). Check out these questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13494693/limit-the-axes-for-plotting-in-matlab), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832993/set-the-view-for-a-2d-matlab-plot/16833081#16833081) or [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133510/axis-equal-in-a-matlab-loglog-plot?rq=1).

```
ylim([ymin ymax])   % or something like:  set(gca,'Ylim',yLimits)
```

sets the axis limits in the current axes to the specified values